# Node acl middleware does not return anything on failure

Tags: node.js, express, acl

I am using Node [Acl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl) with [Acl Sequelize Backend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl-sequelize-backend).
The problem is when Acl authentication middleware fails it does not return anything. The call to API request fails silently. I have no way to handle it on the angular side.
I am using acl middleware like below in code snippet. I have checkout their whole docs but found no way to handle it.
Do i need to override middleware ? or there is way?

```
app.put('/blogs/:id', acl.middleware(), function(req, res, next){…}
```

One more question i have is that does acl store all the permission url in database? and after creating all permission urls we run it only once? and then comment out the permission url's
I am new on this project and have no one to give me domain
Thanks

Comment: technically it should be `app.put('/blogs/:id', acl.middleware, function(req, res, next){…}` and there should be separate definition for `acl.middleware` such as;
`acl.middleware = function(req,res,next) { ...; next(); }`

Comment: I am using what is mentioned in docs.

Comment: can you please elaborate